# Docker compose up Error response from daemon: 400 The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-machine

I have my backend and redis application when I run `docker composeu p` I am getting the errror below

```
docker compose up
Error response from daemon: <html>
<head><title>400 The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>
<center>The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port</center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my compose file

```
version: "3.7"

networks:
  tgwebhook:

services:
  telegramwebhook:
    build: ./
    ports:
      - target: 4000
        published: 4000
        protocol: tcp
        mode: host
    depends_on:
      - redis
    environment:
      - REDIS_HOST=redis
    networks:
      - tgwebhook

  redis:
    image: redis:6.2.5
    ports:
      - target: 6379
        published: 6379
        protocol: tcp
        mode: host
    networks:
      - tgwebhook
```

Here is my docker and compose version

Client: Docker Engine - Community
Version:           23.0.3
API version:       1.42
Go version:        go1.19.7
Git commit:        3e7cbfd
Built:             Tue Apr  4 22:05:48 2023
OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
Context:           default

```
Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          23.0.3
  API version:      1.42 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.19.7
  Git commit:       59118bf
  Built:            Tue Apr  4 22:05:48 2023
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.6.20
  GitCommit:        2806fc1057397dbaeefbea0e4e17bddfbd388f38
 runc:
  Version:          1.1.5
  GitCommit:        v1.1.5-0-gf19387a
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0
```